# Combine Lambda Expressions for OrderBy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I'm trying to order an query using multiple columns. Following is my code and the parameter value. it fails at the line where I try to add two expressions with the error:

> The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.String'
>   and 'System.Single'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
sortColumn = "table1.column1,table2.column1,column3"

public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sortColumn, string direction) {
    string methodName = string.Format("OrderBy{0}", direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");
    MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
    LambdaExpression orderByLambda = null;

    foreach (var fields in sortColumn.Split(',')) {
        memberAccess = null;
        foreach (var property in fields.Split('.')) {
            memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property(memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);
        } if (orderByLambda == null) {
            orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda(memberAccess, parameter);
        } else {
            orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Add(orderByLambda.Body, Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(Expression.Lambda(memberAccess, parameter), parameter), parameter).Body), parameter);
        }
    }
    MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(
              typeof(Queryable),
              methodName,
              new[] { query.ElementType, memberAccess.Type },
              query.Expression,
              Expression.Quote(orderByLambda));
    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
}
```

Comment: use `ThenBy` after your first `OrderBy`

Comment: Perhaps you should be calling OrderBy/ThenBy/ThenBy rather than just trying to use a single OrderBy call?

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that ThenBy is also an option however I really like to get this working as I believe it's possible but stuck with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain your expressions with `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` on the outer level, not on the inner level. Here is how:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sortColumn, string direction) {
    var methodNameFirst = string.Format("OrderBy{0}", direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");
    var methodNameContinue = string.Format("ThenBy{0}", direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");
    Expression result = query.Expression;
    var methodName = methodNameFirst;
    foreach (var fields in sortColumn.Split(',')) {
        Expression memberAccess = null;
        foreach (var property in fields.Split('.')) {
            memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property(memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);
        }
        LambdaExpression orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda(memberAccess, parameter);
        result = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            methodName,
            new[] { query.ElementType, memberAccess.Type },
            result,
            Expression.Quote(orderByLambda));
        methodName = methodNameContinue;
    }
    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
}
```

Comment: I have not tried compiling this, so you may need to make a few adjustments to the code before it compiles. The main thing here is to give you an idea of how to chain `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` programmatically, rather than trying, unsuccessfully, to chain individual member expressions, which requires a lot more work (you'd need to build your own tie-breaking logic), and is not guaranteed to succeed at runtime.

Comment: Thanks!! I was looking at it in a different way and your answer does the job perfectly.

Comment: The only thing I changed was to set null for Expression memberAccess = in order for it be complied.